# Dice Game problems

Tags: wpf

Hi I have made a Dice game. Everything is working fine except the win/lose method of the game. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but whenever I roll the dice it just keeps saying "Roll Again" Even if the dice's sum is not 0.

```
      private void RollDice(out int die1, out int die2)
    {
        die1 = 0;
        die2 = 0;


        Random rand = new Random();

        die1 = 1 + rand.Next(6);
        die2 = 1 + rand.Next(6);
        return;
    }



    private int UpdateGameStatus(int sumDice)
    {
        int die1 = 0, die2 = 0;
        int sum = die1 + die2;
        if (sumDice == 8)
            lblSum.Text = ("You lose!");
        if (sumDice == 4)
            lblSum.Text = ("You lose!");
        if (sumDice == 11)
            lblSum.Text = ("You lose!");
        if (sumDice == 9)
            lblSum.Text = ("You win!");
        if (sumDice == 13)
            lblSum.Text = ("You win!");
        if (sumDice == 0)
            lblSum.Text = ("Roll again!");
        return sum;

    }
    private void btnRoll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int die1 = 0, int die2 = 0
        RollDice(out die1, out die2);
        UpdateGameStatus(sumDice);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign `sumDice` value with `0` before you call `RollDice`. Move `int sumDice = die1 + die2` after `RollDice` function:

```
private void btnRoll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int die1 = 0;
    int die2 = 0;
    RollDice(out die1, out die2);
    int sumDice = die1 + die2;
    UpdateLabel(die1, die2);
    UpdatePictureBoxes(die1, die2);
    UpdateGameStatus(sumDice);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int die1 = 0;
    int die2 = 0;
    RollDice(out die1, out die2);
    int sumDice = die1 + die2; //needs to be moved one down
    UpdateLabel(die1, die2);
    UpdatePictureBoxes(die1, die2);
    UpdateGameStatus(sumDice);
```

Comment: While he does say `sum = die1 + die2` he then ignores the value until he returns it. The code is pretty bad but it's not the cause of his issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do this. It should work. Try to read your code and ensure there are no logical issues before posting it here. This was just a simple logical mistake.

```
private void btnRoll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int die1 = 0;
    int die2 = 0;
    RollDice(out die1, out die2);
    UpdateLabel(die1, die2);
    UpdatePictureBoxes(die1, die2);
    int sumDice = die1 + die2;
    UpdateGameStatus(sumDice);
}
```